# Induction On $a_{n+1}$ Sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, induction

We define a sequence of rational numbers $\{a_n\}$ by putting $a_1=2$ and $$a_{n+1}=3−\frac1{a_n}$$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Put $$\alpha=\frac{3+\sqrt5}2\;.$$

I've shown that $$a_{n+1}−\alpha=\frac{a_n−\alpha}{\alpha a_n}$$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

1) Prove, by induction on $n$, that $|a_n−\alpha|\le|a_1−\alpha|/(4^{n−1}$) for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Please verify that I correctly interpreted everything.

Comment: I typed the question incorrectly, i have edited it now correctly. It should read prove by induction on n, that |a_n−α|≤|a_1−α|/(4^n−1)

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The result clearly holds when $n=1$. The induction step will be easy if you first prove that $$\frac1{\alpha a_n}\le 4$$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ or, equivalently, that $$a_n\ge\frac1{4\alpha}=\frac1{6+2\sqrt5}$$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. One way to do this is to prove by induction that $2\le a_n\le 3$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, which is pretty straightforward.